# Pandas - collapse rows on cell value but retain order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a transcription from an interview which I've converted into a df (I have only recently started learning the pandas framework). The structure of the df is as follows:

```
Timestamp                   Content Speaker
00:00:00.000-00:00:01.100   Content Speaker 1
00:00:03.470-00:00:07.760   Content Speaker 1
00:00:09.340-00:00:13.690   Content Speaker 1
00:00:13.690-00:00:13.760   Content Speaker 2
00:00:14.550-00:00:14.880   Content Speaker 2
00:00:17.000-00:00:30.510   Content Speaker 1
00:00:30.740-00:00:41.930   Content Speaker 2
```

What I want to achieve is to collapse/merge (sorry not sure which term is most suitable here) across speakers and and retain the start and end time for that part of the speaker. The output should look like the one below:

```
**Timestamp                 Content                 Speaker**
00:00:00.000-00:00:13.690   ContentContentContent   Speaker 1
00:00:13.690-00:00:14.880   ContentContent          Speaker 2
00:00:17.000-00:00:30.510   Content                 Speaker 1
00:00:30.740-00:00:41.930   Content                 Speaker 2
```

I don't think I can use `groupby` because it will not retain the hierarchical order of the speakers e.g. it will place all the rows for speaker 1 on top, then all the rows of speaker 2 further down. And from my understanding I cannot use `merge` or `concatenate`. I have the feeling this will be a much more complex operation than I was expecting. Any help/advice/pointers will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) and use the non equality between successive rows as grouper:

```
(df
 .groupby(df['Speaker'].ne(df['Speaker'].shift()).cumsum(),
          as_index=False
         )
 .agg({'Timestamp': 'max', 'Content': ''.join, 'Speaker': 'first'})
)
```

output:

```
                   Timestamp                Content    Speaker
0  00:00:09.340-00:00:13.690  ContentContentContent  Speaker 1
1  00:00:14.550-00:00:14.880         ContentContent  Speaker 2
2  00:00:17.000-00:00:30.510                Content  Speaker 1
3  00:00:30.740-00:00:41.930                Content  Speaker 2
```

update: reworking the Timestamps:

```
df2 = (df
 .groupby(df['Speaker'].ne(df['Speaker'].shift()).cumsum())
 .agg({'Timestamp': 'max', 'Content': ''.join, 'Speaker': 'first'})
 .assign(Timestamp=lambda d: (s:=d['Timestamp'].str.extract('-(.*)', expand=False))
                              .shift(fill_value='00:00:00.000')
                             +'-'+s
        )
)
```

output:

```
                         Timestamp                Content    Speaker
Speaker                                                             
1        00:00:00.000-00:00:13.690  ContentContentContent  Speaker 1
2        00:00:13.690-00:00:14.880         ContentContent  Speaker 2
3        00:00:14.880-00:00:30.510                Content  Speaker 1
4        00:00:30.510-00:00:41.930                Content  Speaker 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This almost works as intended with the exception of the timestamp - likely because I didn't explain myself clearer but look at the desired output . For instance, the start time of the first instance of Speaker 1 is ```00:00:09.340``` when it should be ```00:00:00.000```. The same with the other timestamps.

Comment: @mozway I think the way you solve this only works if there is no time between one speakers `end` and the next `start` . In row 3 the `start` time should be `00:00:17.000` when looking at the original data. @Yiannis can you double check that ? You desired output is also different from that.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare adjacent cells and filter the `df`

**UPDATE**
Due to comments, here the update. Doing so I build my answer off of @mozway's answer since `groupby` is needed now (I think)

```
df[['start', 'end']] = df['Timestamp'].str.split('-',expand=True)
res = (df
 .groupby(df['Speaker'].ne(df['Speaker'].shift()).cumsum())
 .agg({'Timestamp': 'max', 'Content': ''.join, 'Speaker': 'first', 'start':'first', 'end':'last'})
 .assign(Timestamp= lambda x: x[['start', 'end']].apply('-'.join, axis=1))
 .drop(['start', 'end'],axis=1)
)

print(res)

                         Timestamp                Content    Speaker
Speaker                                                             
1        00:00:00.000-00:00:13.690  ContentContentContent  Speaker 1
2        00:00:13.690-00:00:14.880         ContentContent  Speaker 2
3        00:00:17.000-00:00:30.510                Content  Speaker 1
4        00:00:30.740-00:00:41.930                Content  Speaker 2
```

Old answer:

```
res = df[df['Speaker'].ne(df['Speaker'].shift(-1))]

print(res)
                   Timestamp  Content    Speaker
2  00:00:09.340-00:00:13.690  Content  Speaker 1
4  00:00:14.550-00:00:14.880  Content  Speaker 2
5  00:00:17.000-00:00:30.510  Content  Speaker 1
6  00:00:30.740-00:00:41.930  Content  Speaker 2
```

Here is how that works:

```
mask = df['Speaker'].ne(df['Speaker'].shift(-1))
print(mask)

0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
Name: Speaker, dtype: bool
```

The mask is only `True` when the speaker is changing, so you will always get the last row of each speaker.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This almost works as intended with the exception of the timestamp - likely because I didn't explain myself clearer but look at the desired output . For instance, the start time of the first instance of Speaker 1 is ```00:00:09.340``` when it should be ```00:00:00.000```. The same with the other timestamps.

Comment: oh, didn't notice that.

Comment: for some reason I cannot reproduce this answer...
even if I include `df[['start', 'end']]= df['Timestamp'].str.split("-", expand=True)` before main `res=` trick

Comment: thanks, you're right, I changed the way I joined `start` and `end` twice and didn't notice a mistake. It works again on my side.